# Creating a MSP (minimum convex polygone) per day despite some missing datapoints /relocations

Tags: r, mcps

I want to create daily MCPs. Aim is a data frame where I can see the MCP / average home range of Individuals per day. But I do never get any result

```
choughs.sp <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("location_long", "location_lat"), crs = 4326)
result_df <- data.frame()
unique_trackIds <- unique(choughs$trackId)

for (trackId in unique_trackIds) {
  track_data <- choughs[choughs$trackId == trackId, ]
  unique_dates <- unique(as.Date(track_data$timestamp_loc))
  
  for (date in unique_dates) {
    daily_data <- track_data[as.Date(track_data$timestamp_loc) == date, ]
   
    if (nrow(daily_data) >= 5) {
      daily_sp <- daily_data[, c("trackId", "location_lat", "location_long")]
      coordinates(daily_sp) <- c("location_long", "location_lat")
      proj4string(daily_sp) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
      
      mcp_result <- mcp(daily_sp, percent = 100)
      
      mcp_area <- st_area(mcp_result$polygons[[1]])
      
      result_df <- rbind(result_df, data.frame(trackId = trackId, date = date, mcp_area = mcp_area))
    } else {
      cat("Not enough data points for trackId", trackId, "and date", date, ". Skipping...\n")
    }
  }
}
```

I excluded the MCP with less than 5 points and expected at least some results (the data frame contains individuals with more then 5 points per day). But all I got was this:

Error in mcp(daily_sp, percent = 100) :
At least 5 relocations are required to fit an home range

Comment: There is not enough content for us to work with. Please provide more detail and a working reproducible example.